# Can not see Pi Zero on my network

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberry-pi-os

I can't seem to find anything on here already with the same case so I'll go ahead and ask.

I am trying to connect to my pi via SSH, but I can not see the pi on the network.
I have:

1. Flashed the SD card with Raspberry PI OS Lite
2. Added the "SSH" file to the OS root without an extension.
3. Hooked the Pi up to my router using an ethernet cable (which I proved to be functional by testing it in my laptop)

However, when I check my router software, the device is not shown to be connected. I have also tried scanning the network with [Advanced IP Scanner](https://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/) but this doesn't seem to be showing the Pi either.

The Pi is plugged into the mains, and is flashing green so I'd be surprised if it were a power issue, although I'm not sure on this.

Could it be something in the router stopping it? I'm in the UK so it's a Virgin Media Home Hub 3.0.

Comment: Did do name the file "SSH" or "ssh"? file names in linux filesystem are case sensitive. The file should be lower case "ssh".

Comment: I have actually tried both, but either way the Pi is not showing on the network.

Comment: BTW: how do you put an ethernet cable to a pi zero? Is there an ethernet plug? I've never seen one. You can use ethernet over USB AFAIḰ, then you need to activate an additional module. Like in this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HxsYFcortE&ab_channel=ArtsyEngineering Or, do you have an ethernet hat. Perhaps then you need a additional module too. But without knowing how you connect, it is just wild guessing.;-)

Comment: Sorry, I should of been more clear with that! The Pi is connected to the router via this adapter https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Micro-USB-2-0-5pin-to-RJ45-10-100Mbps-Ethernet-Network-Lan-Converter-Adapter/363140613403

Comment: I searched with google for "ky-rd9700 adapter raspi zero" and all links I have looked into state the the adapter runs out of the box. If you use an older raspian there is a chance that the driver is buggy: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1045. So, from what I've read so far, I could not say what the problem is.  Have you the possibillity to add a monitor to the raspi to see it booting? And a keyboard to search in the logs. I think, that's the only reliable way to be sure what happens.

Comment: Yeah, I think that'll be the best bet. I will need to get a hdmi cable, but I'll report back my findings. Thanks for the help.